# java.sql.Date and JTable: update date

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, types, jtable

Hello I am experiencing problems when updating a table cell in the `JTable` with the type `java.sql.Date`. Setter table model:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    try {
        CachRS.absolute(row + 1);
        CachRS.updateObject(col + 1, value);
        CachRS.updateRow();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + " : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

getter table model:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        CachRS.absolute(row + 1);
        obj = CachRS.getObject(col + 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + " : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Date is in the cell, but the attempt to introduce changes to the An exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "date" is of type date but expression is of type character varying
```

A similar problem arises when adding a new line. How to display the date in the table, that would not be such an error?

Comment: It seems you're passing a String as argument, and not a java.sql.Date object. Add `System.out.println(value.getClass())` to the `setValueAt()` method to confirm. Or use a debugger.

Comment: i added:
 
`System.err.println("obj: " + value+" : 
"+value.getClass().getName());`

result:

`obj: 2112-11-09 : java.lang.String`

Comment: So, you have your answer: fix the calling code so that it passes a java.sql.Date and not a String.

Comment: I do not understand. This method is invoked automatically when the cell. I myself, this method never gets called. Incidentally, `string` is in any case even if the column type `int` or `real`. Perhaps the fact that the `CachedRowSet` can not imagine this line as a `java.sql.Date`. The question is just how to do it :)

Comment: You must override getColumnClass() to tell the JTable which renderer and editor it should use. There doesn't exist one for java.sql.Date, so you should return java.util.Date.class for this column, and convert the java.util.Date to a java.sql.Date in the setValueAt() method.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. You said just a little, but I understood. The idea is that the `JTable` should work with `java.util.Date`, but to take and pass a `java.sql.Date` to `CachedRowSet`. Thank you again.